# Blue Theme For Visual Studio 2012 Like 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, themes

I want to change my VS2012 theme to blue theme like in visual studio 2010.

I installed the [Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05), but after installing it I couldn't find any blue theme.

I know there are some threads in SO about that, but all of them are about Theme Editor, which doesn't work in my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you search for "visual studio 2012 update 2" since the link doesn't exist like you said? I did, and I found update 3.

Blue theme update: The Blue theme is now part of [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305), and is no longer included as part of the extension as of version 2.3.  Please ensure VS Update 4 is installed if you want to update the extension while continuing to use the Blue theme.

Comment: but my visual studio have update 2, should i download update 3?

Comment: @MoonLight yes, yes you should.

Answer (score 3):

If you *don't* want to install update 3, which is ~5GB (seriously??), you can instead install Theme Editor extension ver 2.2, which included the Blue theme. I don't know if MS provides the (2.2) download anymore, but I found it here;

http://mirror.nienbo.com/visualstudio-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://projects.sappharad.com/vs2012/) contains some themes for Visual Studio. look at **Visual Studio 2010 Blue Replica** This theme restores Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 back to the colors used in the default theme of Visual Studio 2010

after downloading :Choose Tools -> Customize Colors -> import theme -> select **vs2010.vstheme** then enjoy

PS : These require the [VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) or [VS2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) color theme editor extension